# CombineLatest Selector

Tags: c#, system.reactive, combinelatest

When using CombineLatest with IObservables of differing types I currently am using a selector function that simply passes the tuple through so I can use it in Subscribe method.

```
IObservable<bool> obsBool;
IObservable<int?> obsInt;

obsBool
    .CombineLatest(obsInt, (b,i)=>(b,i)
    .Subscribe(t => doSomething(t.b, t.i));
```

Can this be simplified to get rid of simplify the selector function? (which does nothing)

Comment: The selector function doesn't "do nothing" - it combines two separate arguments into a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension method, though you would lose the easy names:

```
void Main()
{
    IObservable<bool> obsBool = null;
    IObservable<int?> obsInt = null;
    Action<bool, int?> doSomething = null;

    obsBool
        .CombineLatest(obsInt)
        .Subscribe(t => doSomething(t.Item1, t.Item2));
}

public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<(T1, T2)> CombineLatest<T1, T2>(this IObservable<T1> o1, IObservable<T2> o2)
    {
        return o1.CombineLatest(o2, (t1, t2) => (t1, t2));
    }
}
```